# how to disable a textbox whenever outside is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am making a searchbox appears whenever a particular span is clicked. Here is my code

```
<td style="width:35%;text-align:left;">
<span id='tgName' onclick ='showbox()'>Template Group</span>
<input id='searchBox' type='text'style='display:none' onkeypress ='handleEnterKey(this.id)'> </input>
</td>
<td style="width:30%;text-align:left;">
<span id ='ttName' onclick ='showbox1()'>Template Name </span>
<input id='searchBox1' type='text'style='display:none'onkeypress ='handleEnterKey(this.id)'>
</input>
</td>
function showbox()
{
document.getElementById('tgName').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('searchBox').style.display= '';
}

function showbox1()
{
document.getElementById('ttName').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('searchBox1').style.display= '';
}
```

i want if user clicks outside the box then the box disappears and the span appears . How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('searchBox').disabled = true;
```

If you want to disable it without hiding it.

Comment: i want to know to what event should i attach the code given by you? to disable a box when anywhere outside is clicked

Answer (score 0):

use [onBlur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onblur) event of `textbox` and call function `showbox()`

```
 <input id='searchBox' type='text'style='display:none' onblur='showbox()' onkeypress ='handleEnterKey(this.id)'> </input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this script on your page,your task will be achieved.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).mouseup(function (e) {

            var container = $("#searchBox1");

                    if (!container.is(e.target) 
                && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
                    {

                        document.getElementById("searchBox1").style.display = 'none';

                    }
                });

        });

    </script>
```